# Exception on WSO2 CEP 3.1

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, thrift-protocol

i deploy wso2 cep on linux and success into login . i created agents for calling input event adaptor, i got an errors.

```
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:7611,TCP,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:7711
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPublisher.java:273)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:88)
    at com.toogram.agent.publisher.thebulae.AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.initParam(AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.java:45)
    at com.toogram.agent.publisher.thebulae.AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.<init>(AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.java:25)
    at com.toogram.agent.publisher.thebulae.AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.main(AgeAlcoholAnswerAdaptor.java:102)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 210.109.9.177 on port 7711
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:50)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
```

i open port on linux(7611, 7711 port), but i got still same error.
it runs fine when CEP runs on windows. it happens it runs linux.

Please helps...

Comment: Did you try using telnet to verify that the ports are open?

Comment: yes. check the port is open...

Comment: have you properly configured the keystore/truststore in the client?